# Assigning a value to a variable after Firebase return result?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I've been struggling with this for 2 hours now. I'm building an app in Swift, using Firebase Database and storage.

The goal is to update User profile. The user has 2 images - Profile and header. Now, I have to first check if they've selected an image from the photo library, if not -  just get the old URL from the database and submit it back to the database with the rest of the updated information. If it's a new selected image, upload the image to the Storage, get back the URL using `downloadURL` assign it to the `var storageHeaderDownloadedURL` and/or `var storageProfileDownloadedURL` and submit the string values with the rest of the user data to Firebase Database.

The problem is that it obviously assigns the values of an empty `String` (I've declared them as such) BEFORE I get back the downloaded URL. If the user doesn't update the images but the rest of the `UITextFields` it all works, the old URL is submitted to the Firebase Database.

My question is how do I execute the downloaded URL methods for from the storage and then assign it to `var storageHeaderDownloadedURL` and `var storageProfileDownloadedURL` first hand?

```
func updateUserProfile ()
{
    if let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    {
        // Note: Storage references to profile images & profile headers folder
        let storageUserProfileID = Storage.storage.profile_images.child(userID)
        let storageUserHeaderID = Storage.storage.profile_headers.child(userID)

        guard let imageProfile = profileImage.image else { return }

        guard let headerImage = headerImage.image else { return }


        if let newProfileImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageProfile), let newHeaderImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(headerImage)
            {
                storageUserProfileID.put(newProfileImage, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        showAlert(title: "Oops!", msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!, actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        return
                    }
                    // Get the URL from the storage
                    storageUserProfileID.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                        if error != nil
                        {
                            showAlert(title: "Oops!!!", msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!, actionButton: "OK", viewController: nil)
                            return
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if let profileImgDownloadedURL = url?.absoluteString
                            {
                                self.storageProfileDownloadedURL = profileImgDownloadedURL
                                print(self.storageProfileDownloadedURL)
                                self.selectedProfileImage = .True
                            }
                        }

                    })
                })
                storageUserHeaderID.put(newHeaderImage, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        showAlert(title: "Oops!", msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!, actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                        return
                    }

                    // Get the URL from the storage
                    storageUserHeaderID.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                        if error != nil
                        {
                            showAlert(title: "Oops!!!", msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!, actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
                            return
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if let headerImgDownloadedURL = url?.absoluteString
                            {
                                self.storageHeaderDownloadedURL = headerImgDownloadedURL
                                print(self.storageHeaderDownloadedURL)
                                self.selectedHeaderImage = .True
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })


        //Note: Update the info for that user in Database


        print(self.storageHeaderDownloadedURL)
        print(self.storageProfileDownloadedURL)


        var finalHeaderImageURL = String()

        switch self.selectedHeaderImage {

        case .True:
            finalHeaderImageURL = self.storageHeaderDownloadedURL
            break

        case .False:
            finalHeaderImageURL = self.oldHeaderImageInDB
            break

        }
        print(finalHeaderImageURL)


        var finalProfileImageURL = String()

        switch self.selectedProfileImage {

        case .True:
            finalProfileImageURL = self.storageProfileDownloadedURL
            break

        case .False:
            finalProfileImageURL = self.oldProfilePhotoImageInDB
            break

        }
        print(finalProfileImageURL)

        guard let newDisplayName = self.displayNameTextField.text else { return }
        guard let newLocation = self.locationTextField.text else { return }
        guard let newDescription = self.bioTextField.text else { return }
        guard let newWebsite = self.websiteTextField.text else { return }
        guard let newBirthday = self.birthdayTextField.text else { return }

        let newUpdatedUserDictionary = ["imageProfile": finalProfileImageURL,
                                        "imageHeader" : finalHeaderImageURL,
                                        "description" : newDescription,
                                        "location": newLocation,
                                        "displayName": newDisplayName,
                                        "website": newWebsite,
                                        "birthday": newBirthday,
                                        ]
        Database.dataService.updateUserProfile(uid: userID, user: newUpdatedUserDictionary)

        showAlert(title: "Hey", msg: "Your profile was updated", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
         } // Get new uploaded profile and header image URLs
    }
}
```

The enums I use for the switch statements to determine if it's an old URL or a new one:

```
 enum SelectedHeaderImage
 {
  case True
  case False
 }

 enum SelectedProfileImage
 {
 case True
 case False
 }
```

Class outlets:

```
var storageProfileDownloadedURL = String()
var storageHeaderDownloadedURL = String()  

var oldProfilePhotoImageInDB = String()
var oldHeaderImageInDB = String()

var selectedHeaderImage = SelectedHeaderImage.False
var selectedProfileImage = SelectedProfileImage.False`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, your problem is with queuing. You want the code below to execute after the download is complete but it executes in its normal flow. If this is what your problem is then I would suggest you to create another `enum`, with three download states/count. And move that code below you want to be executed later in a function. Increment the state of new `enum` when download is complete. It would look something like this:

```
enum DownloadCount
{
    case Zero
    case One
    case Two
}
var downloadCount = DownloadCount.Zero
```

and in each of the success block of your download complete change it to, I will just write one here to give you the idea of what needs to be done.

```
if let profileImgDownloadedURL = url?.absoluteString
{
     self.storageProfileDownloadedURL = profileImgDownloadedURL
     print(self.storageProfileDownloadedURL)
     self.selectedProfileImage = .True
     if(downloadCount == .Zero)
     {
         downloadCount = DownloadCount.One
     }
     else
     {
         downloadCount = DownloadCount.Two
     }
     self.newAssigningFunction()
}

func newAssigningFunction()
{
    if(downloadCount == .Two)
    {
        //Do your storage/saving work here
    }
}
```

Also if you need to execute this function again, it would be best to set `downloadCount` back to `Zero` at start of your `updateUserProfile` function. Let me know if somethis is unclear or you need further help. Or if this was not your case.

Comment: The problem is with threading, yes. Basically, if the user has selected new images, they need to be uploaded first, then get the download URL, assign them to new variables and submit them to the database with the rest of the information. The problem with your code is the fact that in would not be executed BEFORE that. I was thinking maybe I have to put the whole storage upload on the main queue (synchronous) so it gets executed first? But DispatchQueue.main.async { ... } gives me an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error and its driving me crazy

Comment: I am confused now and not sure what the problem is, you want to execute the same code before the download is complete and also after the download is complete ?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. The code NEEDS to be executed after the strorage functions are executed (hence, the variable storageHeaderDownloadedURL & storageProfileDownloadedURL would both have URL (string) values and they will be used after that in the switch statement to get the proper image url). From what I understood, your code implies that it has to be executed within the Storage Upload/Download function. The whole problem is that that code where the storage upload/downloadURL code its not being executed first and I dont see how your code changes that

Comment: if let profileImgDownloadedURL = url?.absoluteString   ---> THIS happens in the storage upload that's not executed first.

Comment: Either I did not understood your problem or I was unable to explain my solution properly. It probably is the prior. I'll try to explain what I wrote a little better just in case. The if let profileImgDownloadedURL = url?.absoluteString is part of callback from storageUserProfileID.downloadURL. So it will not be executed before the download is complete, due to which your self.storageProfileDownloadedURL will not be empty. And only after both downloads are complete, the code below will run(which is done via moving in a function and handling via enum). Is this not what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I tested your suggestion, it does work indeed, except that the images get uploaded for sure, I see them in the storage, but there's an issue with assigning the new downloaded URLs from the Storage to the database. If the header works and its successfully submitted in the Database, the profile image URL is not and vice versa - not both. I'm trying to figure out why this happens but I assume it has to do with the downloadCount